# Access forgetting public values now

Tags: ms-access, vba, global-variables, ms-access-2016

Access 2016, VBA; I am trying to declare a public variable (User's window login), and it keeps "Forgetting" the variable between the function and the form_load

Module:

```
Option Compare Database

Public vUser As String
```

Start Form:

```
Public Function fnUserID() As String
    Set Wshnetwork = CreateObject("wscript.Network")
    fnUserID = Wshnetwork.UserName
End Function

Public Function SetUserID()
    vUser = fnUserID
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call SetUserID
    txtBox.Value = vUser
End Sub
```

Now I have this exact code (same var names, etc) working in a second Access db. What am I missing that is making this one not work correctly?

Comment: "Option Explicit" maybe in the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work *as is* in a test here, and it works in your other form.

So, recreate the offending form. Somehow the current code module may be corrupted.

Comment: Tried this, and it did not have any effect. Next step I suppose is to recreate the whole db, but I haven't had time to do that yet.

Comment: Then something else not shown here is going on. Nothing except `End` and explicit code can change a global variable.

Comment: Recreated a brand new db and ran into the same problem. Recreated a second time and ... think I found what was happening? I named my code module in the original & second db "Start_Module" I noticed I didn't call it that in the other program which works. So when creating the newest version I left the Module the default "Module1" name and it worked. I am not sure why the naming convention matters.

Comment: You cannot reuse a module name. You may get away with it by spelling it out completely: ModuleName.FunctionName - but that won't work for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Scope is a tricky thing, especially if you're not using `Option Explicit`. You should always use explicit declarations, and use `Option Explicit` at the top of all modules in VBA.

You can explicitly refer to the global scope `vUser` in that module, by adjusting your code to use `ModuleName.vUser`:

```
Public Function fnUserID() As String
    Set Wshnetwork = CreateObject("wscript.Network")
    fnUserID = Wshnetwork.UserName
End Function

Public Function SetUserID()
    Module1.vUser = fnUserID
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call SetUserID
    txtBox.Value = Module1.vUser
End Sub
```

Popular alternatives are:

1. Use a TempVar: `TempVars.vUser`. Advantages include being able to refer to the TempVar in queries, form expressions, and macro's.
2. Use a predeclared class. Advantages include separating authentication code from forms, and making it easier to extend authentication.

Comment: Using Module1.vUser or TempVar claims that they are not defined.

Comment: This now also works that I have renamed things back to Module1